# Linux to Windows ftp script failing "User cannot log in"

Tags: linux, windows, ftp

I am trying to set up a ftp script to work from linux to windows. I keep getting the same results:

> Starting the internal FTP transfer...
>
> Security mechanism not implemented.
>
> Security mechanism not implemented.
>
> KERBEROS_V4 rejected as an authentication type
>
> User cannot log in.
>
> Interactive mode off.

The code that I am using is:

```
HOST=someftpserver
USER='DomainName\\UserName'
PASSWD='%-q186cksx'

echo "Starting the internal FTP transfer..."
ftp -nv $HOST << INSTREAM > /tmp/ftp.log
quote USER $USER
quote PASS $PASSWD
cd /ftpServer/dir
lcd /ftpClient/dir
ascii
put file.txt
bye
INSTREAM
```

When I try manually I am able to log in just fine. The scripted method is the only one not working.

Wanted to see if anyone had any pointers as to why it might be failing.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried to run the script in debug mode - 'bash -x script.sh' ?

Comment: Hi @ALex_hha,  
I did just try that, but no extra ftp logging was present. I am wondering if the script is too fast for the ftp server.

Comment: And what ftp client are you using?

Comment: No, `bash -x script.sh` is not for extra ftp logging, it is to reveal more info into your terminal when running script.sh. Can you run `bash -x script.sh` and copy the terminal's output, not the ftp.log which as you say, has nothing extra added.

Comment: Currently using ftp-0.17-35.el5

Comment: Was able to make this work with:

HOST=someftpserver

USER='DomainName\\UserName'

PASSWD='%-q186cksx'

echo "Starting the internal FTP transfer..."

ftp -nv $HOST << INSTREAM > /tmp/ftp.log

USER $USER $PASSWD

cd /ftpServer/dir

lcd /ftpClient/dir

ascii

put file.txt

bye

INSTREAM

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
HOST=someftpserver
USER='"DomainName\UserName"'
PASSWD='%-q186cksx'
```

The INSTREAM file have a hard time identifying the backslash inside the username. You will have to put the whole username inside double quotes in order for the INSTREAM file to process the credentials correctly.